# Is there a mailing list provider which allows me to include a sign-up form on my site?

Tags: email, mailing-list

What I want to do is present the user with a sign-up form, which contains checkboxes for some of our mailing lists (discussion, not newsletter).

Is there a mailing list provide that has an API for this situation?

Alternatively, is there a provider that provides a widget (for inclusion on my site), which allows users to sign up in a similar way. The drawback of this approach is that data-collection will require a secondary form.

Any suggestions appreciated. Free solutions preferred, but all avenues investigated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use your own newsletter - check between phplist and pommo - and integrate them into your sites; phplist has quite a complicated interface, but it tracks clicks, sent emails, has subscribe/unsubscribe pages and it's fully customizable

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with a lot of providers. If I understood your question, it should be possible with (for example) http://www.yourmailinglistprovider.com/.

They allow you to create custom forms (forms with additional fields like checkboxes) and present you the code you have to add to your page.

The selections of the additional fields are stored in their database (so they are accessible to you).

They also have an extensive API, so you can retrieve or modify any data (like user signups and field selections).